# RabbitMQ unacked messages stuck in a queue even without consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, keda

I have a GPU-driven task that is initiated by messages in a RabbitMQ queue. The queue can be occasionally empty or contain messages in need of processing.

This task operates within a Kubernetes deployment. Due to the significant computational demands of this task, I've implemented Keda for auto-scaling, allowing pods to start only when there are messages in the queue. However, I've noticed that one pod remains continuously active. Upon inspecting the RabbitMQ management UI, I discovered that this is due to the presence of 19 unacknowledged messages in the queue that never get consumed or removed.

Even when I manually removed all the consumers, these unacknowledged messages persisted.

What might be causing this behavior, and what steps can I take to prevent it?

RabbitMQ version: 3.11.16

Comment: If a message is not being removed it most likely a poison message and upon consumption causes an exception so the pod never acknowledges it and probably not sending it to DLQ either so it gets stuck.   Do you have DLQ settings?